# Is it safe to store the value of getContext

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When using the canvas element. Is it safe to call getContext("2d") only once after the page is loaded? Or should I call this function every time I want to draw a frame?

Comment: what do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: @atmd I'm wondering if it's possible that the instance of the context returned might change, leaving the old reference useless.

Comment: i.e.  you set a canvas and context then it somehow got overwritten? I guess its possible if you are creating canvas elements on some sort of user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is save. Calling `getContext("2d")` repeatedly on the same canvas would always get you the same context object.

Comment: I was finally able to find the documentation. [Return the same object as was return the last time the method was invoked with this same first argument](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-canvas-getcontext).